# Web scraping with python / problem of loop in dynamic content and header with panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, web-scraping

I am a complete french newby. I am making a web scraping script in order to get all the cars sales infos (kms, age, color, price etc.) from the website  (future dad here).

My first problem is a problem of loop. It gets me the same page over and over ("I" times...), it doesnt iterate the dynamic content to send the next page after the previous one.

The second one is the header of the dataframe in the csv who repeats for each row.

Thank you very much in advance,

I'm pretty desperate over this.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import pandas as pd
import csv
 
df = pd.DataFrame()
 
#dynamic content modifiers
"""{
    "modelevh[]": "toyota",
    "motorisation[]": "Hybride",
    "pmin": "5000",
    "pmax": "80000",
    "couleur[]": "Rouge",
    "orderby": "date",
    "page": "2"
}"""
 
#how many pages ?
 
url ='https://www.teamcolin-lexus.fr/vehicules-occasion/'
s = requests.Session()
response=s.get(url)
if response.ok:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    page= soup.find('span',{'class':'meta-nav'})
    pages= str(page)
    page_nb=re.search(' sur (.*)<', pages)
    pages_nb=int(page_nb.group(1))
 
"""print(page_nb.group(1))
print(page_nb)"""
 
 
#loop on pages
 
for i in range (1,pages_nb):
    
    payload = {'page': i, 'modelevh[]': 'toyota'}
 
    _ = s.post(url, data=payload)
    r = s.get("https://www.teamcolin-lexus.fr/vehicules-occasion/")
 
#intersting data on the page

    if r.ok:
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        cellules= soup.findAll(class_="liste-vehicule col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between align-items-center")
 
 
    links = []
    for class_ in cellules:
 
    #get links

            link =class_.get('href')
            links.append(link)
 
    for link in links:
            url=link.strip()  
            response=requests.get(url)
            if response.ok:
                    soup_=BeautifulSoup(response.text)
 
                    prix=soup_.find('b',{'class':'price-value'}).text
 
 
                    head=soup_.find('title').text.replace('| LEXUS - Team Colin Lexus', '')
                    #recherche de la table de caractéristiques                
                    table=soup_.find('table',{'class':'table table-sm table-striped d-none d-md-table'})
                    headers=[]

            #get the basic datas table 
     
                    for th in table.find_all("th"):
                        title = th.text
                        headers.append(title)
                        df_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
                    for j in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
                        row_data = j.find_all('td')
                        row = [tr.text for tr in row_data]
                        length = len(df_data)
                        df_data.loc[length] = row    
 
            #add columns
 
                        df_data['Lien annonce']=link
 
                        df_data['Prix']=prix
                        df_data['Modèle']=modele_voiture
 
                        df_data.to_csv('car.csv', encoding='utf-16', mode='a', index = True, header=False)
                        print (df_data)```

https://pastebin.com/7wYHyBtp
````

Comment: Your paging problem is because you do `_ = s.post(url...)` immediately followed by `r = s.get(...)`.  The "post" is sending your page number,  That's the response you need to parse.  Instead, you throw it away and go fetch the first page again.

Comment: Then, you are writing the CSV file in every loop, and each `to_csv` call writes new headers.  You should gather your dataframe over the whole loop instead of creating a new one each time, then call `to_csv` once at the end.  Or, just write the CSV yourself.  It's not clear what `pandas` is bringing to this party.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
How can I "not throw it away ?"

Comment: Delete the `s.get` line and do `r = s.post(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example how to get information from the pages and save it to pandas DataFrame:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.teamcolin-lexus.fr/vehicules-occasion/"
payload = {"orderby": "date", "page": ""}

data = []
current_page = 1
while True:
    payload["page"] = current_page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.post(url, data=payload).content, "html.parser"
    )

    cars = soup.select("a.liste-vehicule")
    if not cars:
        break

    for a in cars:
        print("Getting {}".format(a["href"]))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(a["href"]).content, "html.parser")
        row = {
            "Type": soup.title.text.split("|")[0].strip(),
            "Price": soup.select_one(".price-value").text,
            "Url": a["href"],
        }
        data.append(row)
        for th in soup.select(".mx-auto th"):
            row[th.get_text(strip=True)] = th.find_next("td").get_text(
                strip=True
            )

    current_page += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Saves all ~700 cars into `data.csv` (screenshot from Libre Office):

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, I will test it !